# Mutating string extension causing huge CPU impact

Tags: swift, string, replace

I created a small extension for the `String` class to conveniently remove characters from it. Here is what it looks like:

```
mutating func drop(characters chars: [String]) {
    for c in chars {
        self = self.replacingOccurrences(of: c, with: "")
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
//string = ""Test"" (contains quotes), should be "Test" (w/ quotes)
string.drop(characters: ["\""])
```

Now, when I call this function on a string, the CPU goes through the roof causing the app to eventually crash.

Any ideas why?
Thanks!

---

#### Update

I realized that the following code too causes huge CPU impact, so it's apparently not an issue about my extension but something else:

```
string = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "")
```

#### Update #2 / Solution

I found the issue. I was executing said statement in a while loop that ended once the string inside `superString` did not exist anymore. To achieve that, I removed `string` by `replacingOccurrences` from `superString`. I realized, that *after* executing the statement `string` was obviously not like it's former occurence in `superString`.
Long story short: I had to execute the statement *after* removing `string` from `superString` or else the while loop would never end which cause the CPU impact & crash.

Thanks for trying to help nonetheless!

Comment: If you have a solution to your own question then you should either delete your question or post the solution as an answer and accept it if you think it's important enough to keep around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution

I was executing said statement in a `while loop` that ended once the `string` inside `superString` did not exist anymore.
To achieve that, I removed `string` by `replacingOccurrences` from `superString`. I realized, that after executing the statement `string` was obviously not like it's former occurence in `superString`.

Long story short: I had to execute the statement after removing string from `superString` or else the `while loop` would never end which cause the CPU impact & crash.

Visually:

```
while superString.contains(pattern: myPattern) {
    var string = superString.searchFor(myPattern).get(0)!
    textfile = textfile.replacingOccurrences(of: string, with: "")

    string.drop(charactersInRegex: ["\""])
    myArray.append(string)
}
```

**instead of**

```
while superString.contains(pattern: myPattern) {
    var string = superString.searchFor(myPattern).get(0)!
    string.drop(charactersInRegex: ["\""])
    myArray.append(string)

    textfile = textfile.replacingOccurrences(of: string, with: "")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion to avoid mutating the string more than once, which has a performance penalty, could be rewrite your function like this:

```
mutating func drop(charactersIn string: String) {
    self = String(
        self.characters.filter { !string.characters.contains($0) }
    )
}

// And then for example:
string.drop(charactersIn: "\"tT")
```

Comment: Thanks, I already implemented that in the my full function before but apparently that still didn't keep it form crashing.